# Provide parameter to PS script stored as a string

Tags: powershell, ps

This is the command that I provided to the customer before:

```
iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('URL'))
```

It downloads PS script as a string from URL location and executes the script.

Now I need to pass parameter to this script

```
iex (((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('URL')) -Parameter 'parameter')
```

And it is not working because string not accepts parameters

I need to create the simple command (it is important) that will download the script from URL and accept parameters. Otherwise I would save this string to ps1 file and execute it passing the parameter

Could you please help me with that? I am new to PS

Answer (score 2):

Try the following approach:

```sh
& ([scriptblock]::Create(
     (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('URL')
  )) 'Parameter'
```

Note:

- The above runs the script text in a *child* scope, due to use of `&`, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-), as would happen with local invocation of a script file, whereas [`Invoke-Expression`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-expression) (`iex`) runs it in the *current* scope, i.e. as if it were called with `.` , the [dot-sourcing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#dot-sourcing-operator-). Change `&` to `.` if you want this behavior.
- To download the script, you could alternatively use PowerShell's [`Invoke-RestMethod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod) (`irm`) cmdlet: `Invoke-RestMethod 'URL'` or `irm 'URL'`
- [`[scriptblock]::Create()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock.Create) creates a PowerShell [*script block*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks), which can then be invoked with `&` (or `.`), while also accepting arguments.

---

As for **what you tried**:

`Invoke-Expression` (`iex`) - which should [generally be avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51252636/45375) - has several drawbacks when it comes to executing a script file's content downloaded from the web:

- It doesn't support passing arguments, as you've discovered.
- An `exit` statement in the script text would cause the current PowerShell session to exit *as a whole*.
- As noted, the code executes *directly in the caller's scope*, so that its variables, functions, ... *linger* in the session after execution (however, it's easy to avoid that with `& { iex '...' }`).

[GitHub issue #5909](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5909#issuecomment-461192202) discusses enhancing the [`Invoke-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command) cmdlet to robustly support download and execution of scripts directly from the web.